# Error in Twilio IVRS call

Tags: twilio

I am getting the following error while transferring the incoming call to a PSTN number.
Error: 13214 - Dial: Invalid callerId value
The number to which the call is transferred is verified and saved in Twilio. When the user pushes '2', the caller hears-'Transferring the call' and then immediately another message is received which tells that there has been an Application error.

```
 else if ($user_pushed == 2)
{
    echo '<Say>Transferring the call</Say>';
    echo '<Dial>+1(10_digit_number)</Dial>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience when you do not pass a 'callerId' attribute on the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) command it try's to use the number which is calling in as the caller ID. Post the log from the Dev Logs in Twilio and show more of the code for which the process is flowing through on your PHP script.

Comment: I had not included the callerid attribute. Included now and its working fine!